# Number of permutations following given order

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, algorithms, order-theory

I have $n$ numbers and ordered sets $s_i$ of some of these numbers, I need to calculate the number of all the possible permutations of the $n$ numbers respecting the orders in the sets $s_i$. I found a way to calculate the number of possible permutations when the sets $s_i$ are disjoint, but not when they are not disjoint. We suppose that the orders of the sets $s_i$ are compatible.

For example:
$n=5$

$s_1 = (1, 2,  3)$

$s_2 = (5, 2)$

In this example, what is the total number of the possible permutations of the numbers from 1 to 5 respecting the orders in $s_1$ and $s_2$.

I would appreciate any suggestions for the general case.

Comment: Not sure the rules are clear.  Since (as per your example) the special subsets might overlap, are we to assume that the orders are compatible? You wouldn't want $s_1=(1,2,3)$ and $s_2=(3,2)$ for instance.  Anyway, for your example there are only $1523$ and $5123$ with $4$ going wherever it likes in both cases.

Comment: And, what is the source of this problem?  It looks more like a programming question than a math problem...For general cases, sorting out the various overlaps could get quite messy.

Comment: yes, we assume that the orders are compatible. I give a simple example, but I need to calculate the number for the general case.

Comment: And why do you need to calculate this?  Again, it seems to me that this is a programming issue.  I can't imagine what a closed form solution might look like.

Comment: Even testing for consistency seems challenging.  you could have special sets like $(1,2,7)$, $(6,7,5)$, $(3,5,2)$ for instance.  Not instantly obvious that these are contradictory.  I suggest starting by writing code to check consistency.

Comment: this is an exercise I am trying to solve in programming, but I was wondering if we can find a formula to find that number and that make a code to calculate it. In this questions https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2153992/number-of-permutations-with-constraints they suggested a formula that is valid when the sets $s_i$ are disjoint

Comment: we assume that the sets $s_i$ are compatible, no need to check that

Comment: Yes, if the sets are disjoint this looks manageable. But that is a very special case.

Comment: Checking consistency is a natural first step here.  Next step:  I would first use the given orders to determine the entirety of the partial order.  That is, list all pairs $(x,y)$ with $x<y$ in the given partial order.

Comment: what do you mean by consistency?

Comment: As I have said, check that the orders do not contradict.  I understand that you say that this is an assumption, but I think that confirming it is a natural building block in the code.  If that is challenging, I would think that the full problem was hopeless.  Just my view, of course.

Comment: yes, we assume that the orders do not contradict, because they were constructed in a previous step. In your answer, once we have the partial orders of all pairs, what can we do next please?

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to work on this.  As I mentioned, it feels like a programming challenge problem.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Note that we can assume the sets $\{S_j\}_j$ exhaust $[n]$; if not, we just add the remaining numbers in as singletons.  This gives a partial order $P$ on $[n]$; $x\leq_P y$ iff $(\exists j)(x\text{ appears before }y\text{ in }S_j)$.  Conversely, any partial order can be given in your form; take $\{S_{x,y}\}_{x,y\in[n]}$ where $S_{x,y}=\begin{cases}
(x,y) & x\leq_P y \\
x & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$.

A permutation preserving the $\{S_j\}_j$ is a [linear extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_extension) of $P$; as Wiki points out, counting linear extensions is `#P`-complete, and so intractable to compute in general.  OTOH, Wiki says it can be approximated quite well via a randomized algorithm, citing [Bubley & Dyer, "Faster random generation of linear extensions" (*Discrete Mathematics* 201: 1999)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X98003331).

Comment: thank you for your answer. A part from the exhaustive enumeration of all the possible permutations and check for each one if all the  orders are satisfied, is there another more efficient way of calculating the number?